# Codeigniter - PHP - unserialize(): Error at offset 185 of 411 bytes

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, serialization

Hi i got a strange error on Codeigniter + nginx server.

I get a log Error which is :

```
ERROR - 2013-07-17 15:01:22 --> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize(): Error at offset 185 of 411 bytes /system/libraries/Session.php 726
```

so i putted this code to Session.php library to log what the data serializing is:

```
function _unserialize($data)
    {   

        log_message('error', var_export($data, true));

        $data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));

        if (is_array($data))
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val)
            {
                if (is_string($val))
                {
                    $data[$key] = str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $val);
                }
            }

            return $data;
        }

        return (is_string($data)) ? str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $data) : $data;
    }
```

and this returns this in log file:

```
ERROR - 2013-07-17 15:01:22 --> 'a:11:{s:7:"user_id";s:2:"93";s:14:"user_name";s:7:"Michael";s:13:"user_last";s:5:"Russa";s:10:"user_email";s:22:"moo@ail.com";s:13:"user_loc";s:12:"??????";s:13:"user_lat";s:10:"55.72420";s:14:"user_lon";s:10:"37.6484220";s:16:"user_grav";s:32:"7ef03623b352c9b62f6a642ef4b40434";s:11:"user_ps";s:3:"152";s:9:"beta_u";s:3:"yes";s:12:"is_mod";s:4:"true";}'
ERROR - 2013-07-17 15:01:22 --> Severity: Notice  --> unserialize(): Error at offset 185 of 411 bytes /project/system/libraries/Session.php 726

**`NB: the serialized key values are not real, i changed them just to show you what that returns.`**
```

I also controlled php.ini and `magic_quotes_rcp = off` and also `magic_quotes_runtime = off;`

i'm using `UTF-8 in Codeigniter, HTML and in all database tables and database itself`.

Also i'm using the `Session DB` in Codeigniter

Can't understand what's going wrong, what it could be?

Is session too huge? It uses a db to store session so i'm wondering how it could be too huge :(

> The ONLY thing i can highlight is that i updated the session db field
>   userdata FROM TEXT to LONGTEXT , but with both types the error persists.

any help appriciated thanks.

Comment: The length of your strings are not correct in serialized data.  
ex: `s:11:"user_ps"` must be `s:7:"user_ps"`

Comment: @bystwn22 **`NB: the serialized key values are not real, i changed them just to show you what that returns.`** ;)

Comment: i grant you they were ok (the reals values i mean)

Answer (score 1):

I simply increased 'user_data' field in sessions table from TEXT to MEDIUMTEXT and it solved this issue